# tagged pointer specialization based on alignof

Tags: c++

I'm trying to design a tagged pointer class where the least significant bit of the pointer is available as a flag, but only if it is actually available, i.e., the alignment of the pointed-to type is larger than 1.

The following works, except for the problem at the end, where alignof() cannot be applied to an incomplete type.

```
#include <cstdint> //for std::uintptr_t

template<typename T> struct always_tagged_pointer {
    static_assert(alignof(T) != 1, ""); //lsb available
    union { T* ptr; std::uintptr_t bits; };
    //rest of implementation omitted
};
template<typename T, size_t alignof_T> struct maybe_tagged_pointer_impl {
    static_assert(alignof(T) != 1, ""); //lsb available
    union { T* ptr; std::uintptr_t bits; };
    //rest of implementation omitted
};
template<typename T> struct maybe_tagged_pointer_impl<T, 1> {
    static_assert(alignof(T) == 1, ""); //lsb not available
    T* ptr; bool flag;
    //rest of implementation omitted
};
template<typename T> using maybe_tagged_pointer = maybe_tagged_pointer_impl<T, alignof(T)>;

maybe_tagged_pointer<int>  a; //OK.
maybe_tagged_pointer<char> b; //OK.

struct foo {
    int i; //so that alignof(foo)!=1 for this test
    void fun1(always_tagged_pointer<foo> p) {} //Ok.
    void fun2( maybe_tagged_pointer<foo> p) {} //error: invalid application of 'alignof' to an incomplete type 'foo'
};
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want? Perhaps with a different design?

Comment: Alignment and memory locations are different concerns (An even aligned type might be stored at an odd address).

Comment: Can't you move `fun2` outside of `foo` ?

Comment: @DieterLücking Engineers that design such platforms/implementations don't tend to survive for long.

Answer (score 0):

Would this 'relaxed' approach do for you?

```
struct foo {
    int i; //so that alignof(foo)!=1 for this test
    void fun1(always_tagged_pointer<foo> p) {} //Ok.
    // with the discipline that the calling code will always pass a foo
    // for the U type, this may work
    template <type U> void fun2( maybe_tagged_pointer<U> p) {
       // will this create one more compile err??
       using dummy_t=std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,foo>::value>
    }
};
```

Comment: Maybe the discipline could be enforced with a compile-time assert : `static_assert(std::is_same<U, foo>::value, "...");` ?

Comment: `template <type U> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U, foo>> fun2(..)` would be an other option.